# Calcular média com exame final se for reprovado nas notas normais

Tags: python, algoritmo

> 1. Ler os valores de quatros notas escolares bimestrais de um aluno     representado as pelas variáveis N1,N2,N3,N4. Calcular a média aritmética (variável MD1) desse aluno e apresentar a mensagem "Aprovado com média' se a média obtida for maior igual a 7.0; caso contrario o programa deve solicitar a quinta nota de exame, representada por NE) e calcular uma nova media, variável (MD2) entre a nota de exame e a primeira média. Se o valor da media for maior ou igual a 5, apresentar a mensagem "Aprovado com média"; caso contrario apresente a mensagem "Reprovado com média". Apresentar o valor da média ao lado de cada uma das mensagens.

Aqui foi a solução que encontrei:

```
# mudei as variaveis e a quantidade de notas, mas a essencia é a mesma. do que foi pedido.

a = float(input('Nota 1: '))
b = float(input('Nota 2: '))
c = float(input('nota 3: '))
m1 = (a + b) / 2
if m1 >= 7:
    print('Aprovado media %f' % m1)
else:
    m2 = (m1 + c) / 2
    if m2 >= 5:
        print('Aluno aprovado media %f' % m2)
    else:
        if m2 < 4:
            print('Reprovado media %f' % m2)
enter = input('\nPressione <ENTER> para encerrar...')
```

Essa solução seria satisfatória?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

De cara não está certo porque o exercício manda pedir 4 notas e você pede só 3 e divide por 2 sei lá porque (não sei o que espera de melhor fazendo isso errado, se for economizar a digitação de alguns caracteres, só causou confusão), depois começa fazer algo completamente sem sentido e que não é o que o enunciado pede (deve pedir outra nota). Os nomes das variáveis realmente não importam muito.

Eu acho a fórmula para pegar a nova média não pode usar a média antiga dividindo por 2 porque passa dar mais peso para a nota nova, mas é o que o enunciado pede, então vamos lá.

Não me preocupei com um possível erro de digitação que quebraria a aplicação, o correto é tratar isto.

```
a = float(input('Nota 1: '))
b = float(input('Nota 2: '))
c = float(input('nota 3: '))
d = float(input('nota 4: '))
m1 = (a + b + c + d) / 4
if m1 >= 7:
    print('Aprovado media %f' % m1)
else:
    e = float(input('nota exame: '))
    m2 = (m1 + e) / 2
    if m2 >= 5:
        print('Aluno aprovado media %f' % m2)
    else:
        print('Reprovado media %f' % m2)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/sSdApw). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/AveragePlusExam). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/AveragePlusExame.py).

Comment: Sim amigo eu tenho ciencia que a resolução proposta por mim esta diferente do enunciado. E foi exatamente por isso que fiz questao de por um comentario na resolução que fiz, explicando que estava diferente mas que a ideia central era a mesma. Mas entendi. E obrigado por ajudar.

Comment: Se o aluno não passou com as notas regulares tendo uma média 7, divide-se a nota obtida por 2 e então ele vai fazer um super provão ferrado para tentar se salvar valendo metade da nota do semestre, mas aí a média é 5. Na faculdade que me formei (UFMT) era exatamente assim.

Comment: @VictorStafusa é, tem dessas, eu já vi a prova de salvação substituir tudo o que valeu no semestre, ou seja, era mais arriscado (nem tanto porque se sabia que era mais fácil), mas dava menos trabalho só fazer ela. Era uma espécie de recuperação virtual já que não tinha aula de reforço, alias nunca vi isso sério, nem em escola alemã toda certinha recuperava o aluno de verdade, era só um castigo (frequentar mais aulas e fazer muitos trabalhos em casa) pra quem não teve nota normal e outra chance de ter a nota.